# Randomizing a primary key with character a value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a primary key on a table(as seen on the picture below) with a value of character. These primary key is a foreign key on another table and i want to input them but in a random way meaning some of them may not be inputted on that table. Is there any way to do it?

[image: primary key of inventory table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an 8-digit, zero-padded string, then:

```
select lpad((random()*100000000)::text, 8, '0')
```

If you want a valid matching value from the other table, you can use something like this:

```
select pk
from othertable
order by random()
limit 1;
```

Note:  This is expensive if the other table is even moderately sized.

Comment: is there any way to insert these by randomly inputting any data meaning one pk can be call again?

Comment: @ElijahLeis . . . I don't understand the comment.  These are random, so there is a small chance that a given value could appear multiple times.  If you want uniqueness, `random()` is not the way to go.  Use an `identity`/`serial` column or UUID.